# issues launching a node/redis/socket app onto heroku

Tags: heroku, redis, node-modules

I'm trying to launch my app onto Heroku and am getting hung up in a few places.
I have set up the app using the 'node.js' process provided, and am using the addon 'Redis Cloud,' but it is getting hung up.

using `heroku logs --tail` I get a long string of error messages, but most of them stem from node_modules which i have not written or touched.

An error similar to this occurs a few (3) times, but the general structure of it is:

```
2015-04-22T22:36:03.497059+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-04-22T22:36:05.119390+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2015-04-22T22:36:06.597719+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-04-22T22:36:06.597695+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-04-22T22:36:07.093093+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:72
2015-04-22T22:36:07.093394+00:00 app[web.1]:               ^
2015-04-22T22:36:07.092975+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-22T22:36:07.095896+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
2015-04-22T22:36:07.095887+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
2015-04-22T22:36:07.095890+00:00 app[web.1]:     at RedisClient.on_error (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:196:24)
2015-04-22T22:36:07.095891+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:106:14)
2015-04-22T22:36:07.095894+00:00 app[web.1]:     at net.js:441:14
2015-04-22T22:36:07.095893+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
2015-04-22T22:36:07.093363+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2015-04-22T22:36:07.090979+00:00 app[web.1]: listening on *:15286
2015-04-22T22:36:07.894314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-04-22T22:36:07.893549+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-22T22:36:07.878999+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2015-04-22T22:36:09.837516+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2015-04-22T22:36:11.600503+00:00 app[web.1]: Recommending WEB_CONCURRENCY=1
2015-04-22T22:36:11.600483+00:00 app[web.1]: Detected 512 MB available memory, 512 MB limit per process (WEB_MEMORY)
2015-04-22T22:36:12.312046+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-04-22T22:36:12.312797+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2015-04-22T22:36:12.320402+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
2015-04-22T22:36:12.320405+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
2015-04-22T22:36:12.320394+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
2015-04-22T22:36:12.320398+00:00 app[web.1]:     at RedisClient.on_error (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:196:24)
2015-04-22T22:36:12.320400+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:106:14)
2015-04-22T22:36:12.320403+00:00 app[web.1]:     at net.js:441:14
2015-04-22T22:36:12.312260+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:72
2015-04-22T22:36:12.308956+00:00 app[web.1]: listening on *:15286
2015-04-22T22:36:12.313581+00:00 app[web.1]:               ^
2015-04-22T22:36:13.172938+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-04-22T22:36:13.163265+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
```

there are a few other errors which may or may not be tied in, but they are vague (`code=H10` just seems to indicate that there was a problem... not what it was).

```
2015-04-22T14:57:01.110155+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=appName.herokuapp.com request_id=2b8587e3-f519-45e7-bb9f-5f0953e9440a fwd="50.150.70.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-22T14:57:02.558241+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=appName.herokuapp.com request_id=d0e44873-30cb-4a34-94ed-bcc754927dd7 fwd="50.150.70.220" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-22T21:47:17.963341+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=appName.herokuapp.com request_id=d320b50b-0926-4de7-83d0-a9a4208fb6c5 fwd="38.140.30.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-04-22T21:47:19.564687+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=appName.herokuapp.com request_id=9307e6c0-2731-438d-abae-9266634b05ba fwd="38.140.30.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

So, is this enough information to determine if this is why/where the app is getting hung up?

Answer (score 0):

Given this:

```
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
```

Suggests that your code is attempting to establish a connection to a local Redis server. When using Redis Cloud on Heroku you need to open a connection to the Redis database whose endpoint and password are stored in the `REDISCLOUD_URL` env var.